# Check if string starts with any of two (sub) strings

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass a number of options for a bolean function and I wrote it like this:

```
s = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVNG8jjZN7k'
s.startswith('http://') or s.startswith('https://')
```

But I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to write it,
something like:

```
s.startswith('http://' or 'https://')
```

Comment: `any(s.startswith(protocol) for protocol in ['http://', 'https://'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.startswith` can take a tuple of strings as an argument. It will return true if the string starts with *any* of them.

```
s.startswith(('http://', 'https://'))
```

However, it might be simpler to use a regular expression to capture the idea of the `s` being optional:

```
bool(re.match('https?://', s))
```

If the match succeeds, you get back a truthy `re.Match` object. If the match fails, you get back the falsy value `None`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `urllib.parse.urlparse`

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse


url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVNG8jjZN7k'

if urlparse(url).scheme in ("http", "https"):
   ...
```

More useful methods in the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse